# Assign value to array elements, given some condition

Tags: arrays, vector, indexing, modelica

Let's say I have vectors

```
Real x[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
```

and

```
Real y[5]={0,0,0,0,0};
```

I want to assign values to elements of `y` given some condition on `x`, say for example, for every element in `x` greater than or equal to `3`, corresponding `y` should be set to `1`,  for every `x<3: y=sin(x)`

In matlab, I would have written as follows:

```
  y(x>=3)=1;
  y(x<3)=sin(x(x<3));
```

so

```
x=[1 2 3 4 5]
```

Results in

```
y=[sin(1) sin(2) 1 1 1]
```

Can something similar be done in Modelica, and if so, how?

Comment: I think something like this would work: y = if (x[i] >= 3) then 1 else sin(x[i]) for i in size(x, 1);

Comment: @Adrian: The syntax in your example seems wrong, at least for equations. Where would you put that?

Comment: I haven't tested it so it might be a bit off. In equations you would use a for loop.

Comment: Maybe you can move the assignment into a function, and then use automatic vectorization as described here: https://mbe.modelica.university/behavior/arrays/functions/#vectorization
Also make sure to read about array comprehension: https://mbe.modelica.university/behavior/arrays/construction/#array-comprehensions

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no array filtering in Modelica, so `x>=3` does not work and there is nothing available that is comparable to that.

But still there are some ways get the resulting vectors, depending if you want an equation or an algorithm. In a model using equations you could e.g. use an [array constructor with one iterator](https://specification.modelica.org/maint/3.5/arrays.html#array-constructor-with-one-iterator):

```
model DemoModel
  Real x[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
  Real y[:]= {if i >= 3 then 1 else sin(i) for i in x};
end DemoModel;
```

With this method all elements are assigned at once. In models its not possible to update only the values which match a criteria (or at least I don't know how to do so), since:

- Vector sizes must be known during translation
- Every element of a vector needs an equation

With a filter the number of equations would vary dynamically, depending on the values of `x` and the condition.

Inside functions you have more possibilities (you can have flexible array sizes), but when you use the output of the function in a model you are facing the same limitations again.

Comment: Thanks Marco, I think you are on the right track, 

In this case, "x" happens to be "1,2,3,4,5"  i.e. "i" of the "for i in x"-expression (I suspect are the same?) but lets say x=[100,10,0.1,0.01,0.001], and so the condition is, for example (matlab syntax)

`for i=1:5`

 `if x(i)>=10`

  ` y(i)=1`

 `end`

`end`

Comment: Thanks Marco, I think you are on the right track, 

In this case, "x" happens to be "1,2,3,4,5"  i.e. "i" of the "for i in x"-expression (I suspect are the same?) but lets say x=[100,10,0.1,0.01,0.001], and so the condition is, for example (matlab syntax)
    `for i=1:5;
      if x(i)>=10;
      y(i)=1;
    end;
end;`

(*it seems the editor ignores new line, i have not yet figured out how to write comments properly*)

Comment: Here's what the formula actually looks like.  
y :=vector((1)./ ((1).+ (log(x100 ./ x) / log(x100 / x50)) .^ b));   


Here, x is the independent variable, and y is what is evaluated. b,x50 and x100 are parameters. The expression evaluates y as "nan" ("not a number") for x>x100, but I want instead to assign the value "1" to y, where the corresponding x is greater than x100.

Comment: I managed to solve it with a "for" loop, changing elements one by one, but I'm thinking there should be a more compact syntax, similar to matlab's " y(x>=x100)=1 "

Comment: No, there is nothing like that. See the updated answer. foor loops might be the simplest solution.

Comment: Regarding the first two comments: The variable `i` takes all values of `x`, no matter if they are integers or reals.

Comment: Thanks again Marco, this is valuable help. For a beginner like myself,  knowing what does not work, is equally important as knowing what does work, so you don't waste time trying to accomplish something that can't be done.